# Canvas to Blob and then to PHP server

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, blob

I am trying to do this:

1. Generate blobs. For this I am using the [JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) library.
2. Save those blob to a php server.

Currently I have this

```
onFrame: function(canvas) {
 if(StartRecording == true) {
  canvas.toBlob(
   function (blob) { 

   }, 
   'image/jpeg');
  }
}
```

where blob is the generated blob. This function will generate x blobs. My question is how to collect all blobs to one file and then upload this file to a php server.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: try to send and AJAX POST request to server with blob or use a flash plugin to send the data. You cannot "emulate" sending post with all blobs as a single file because JS API won't allow you to send a file from user disk without user interaction. Additionally take care about blob size, don't send more than few MB to server, this will kill your server and make application very slow